# SW_SMOOTHSCROLL ScrollWindowEx

Tags: c++, winapi

How to use the flag `SW_SMOOTHSCROLL` of the WinApi [ScrollWindowEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-scrollwindowex)?

> SW_SMOOTHSCROLL
> Scrolls using smooth scrolling. Use the HIWORD portion of the flags parameter to indicate how much time, in milliseconds, the smooth-scrolling operation should take.

**Independent** of what value I input as the time `100` or `9999`, it continues scrolling with the same speed, would like to ask if someone knows how to properly use this flag?

```
   case WM_VSCROLL:
   {
        RECT rc;
        int CurPos = scrollY;
        int TemPos = CurPos;
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            case SB_TOP:            CurPos = 0; break;
            case SB_LINEUP:         CurPos = (CurPos > 0)? CurPos - 1 : 0; break;
            case SB_THUMBPOSITION:  CurPos = HIWORD(wParam); break;
            case SB_THUMBTRACK:     CurPos = HIWORD(wParam); break;
            case SB_LINEDOWN:       CurPos = (CurPos < 240)? CurPos + 1 : 240; break;
            case SB_BOTTOM:         CurPos = 240; break;
            case SB_ENDSCROLL:      break;
        }
    
      SetScrollPos(hwnd, SB_VERT, CurPos, TRUE);
      TemPos = CurPos - TemPos;

      UINT flags;
      flags = MAKELONG(SW_SCROLLCHILDREN | SW_SMOOTHSCROLL | SW_ERASE |
      SW_INVALIDATE, 100);
        
      ScrollWindowEx(hwnd, 0, -, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, flags);
    
      break;
   }
```

Comment: The smooth scroll offered by this function is pretty simplistic and has a few limitations. It won't scroll less than 10 pixels every iteration, and it also aims to complete the entire operation in no more than 10 iterations. These constraints limit the total time the scroll can take, irrespective of your requested time.